# load_lora_weights() not loading weights

Tags: pytorch, tensor, huggingface, stable-diffusion

trying to load [checkpoint from civitai](https://civitai.com/models/57319?modelVersionId=99805) to a [huggingface stable diffusion model](https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4).

Trying to use load_lora_weights() function described [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/using-diffusers/other-formats).

It works perfectly when trying to load [another lora file](https://civitai.com/api/download/models/19998).

When trying to load model 99805 with load_lora_weights() I get error `ValueError: None does not seem to be in the correct format expected by LoRA or Custom Diffusion training.`

I download it using `!wget https://civitai.com/api/download/models/99805 -O testerino.safetensors`

How can I load the weights to huggingface model?